# How to multiply a single layer of a neural network by a real number?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The question's pretty straightforward. I want to multiply a single layer in my neural network by a number.

This number is `n = max(abs(input))`, so that the actual input will be `input/n`, while the output will be `output*n`. I want to know if there's a way to insert these calculations in my neural network model.

On a sidenote, I want to do this because I read somewhere that a common solution is to normalize the inputs then de-normalize the outputs, and that's what I want to do. However, in my Multi-input neural network, one of the inputs is binary data while the other are regular real numbers, so I want to normalize only this real input, and de-normalize a specific downstream layer.

Comment: You can either create a custom layer by subclassing the Keras Layer class as described here - [Keras Custom Layer](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/) and use that in you neural network or you can use the Lambda layer for this as described here - [Keras Lambda Layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/).

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you want to multiply the output of a layer by a scalar quantity `n`. You can use a custom model:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(10)
        self.dense2 = Dense(20)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dense2(scalar_value*x)
```

I don't know how your model is built, but you can add the layers you need in the **init** method and call them in the call method to produce the final results.